# Question abt PHP variables by refernce & Zend_Auth

Tags: php

its possible to do a

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
```

but i thought that is not passing a variable by reference?

... or do i need to use the instance of Zend_Auth by instance anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are always passed "by-reference" as of PHP5. Therefore `Zend_Auth::getInstance()` and `$auth` *are* the same object instance.